# Cannot subscript a value of type [MPMediaItem] #2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mpmediaitem

I know the question has been asked in the exact same way here [cannot subscript a value of type [MPMediaItem]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799861/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-mpmediaitem) , but I don´t get his solution working.

```
cell.textLabel!.text = allSongs![indexPath.row]
```

is what i´m trying.

allSongs is declared like this `var allSongs =  [MPMediaItem]?()`

Comment: What error are you getting? Make sure row is smaller than the count of your array.

Comment: My error is exactly like the title "Cannot subscript a value of type [MPMediaItem]"  Row is allSongs.count

Comment: You're assigning an `MPMediaItem` to a property that needs a `String`

Comment: How can I convert an MPMediaItem into a String? @dan

Comment: Depends what you want to show in your label. `MPMediaItem` has many string properties: `title`, `albumTitle`, `artist`, etc.

Comment: I want to show the title @dan

Comment: Then do `cell.textLabel!.text = allSongs![indexPath.row].title`

Comment: that worked! @dan but now I can´t filter... the error is `Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something link this:

```
 cell.textLabel!.text = allSongs![indexPath.row].valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as? String
```